# How to fix _castError List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast, currently i am sending form data in the body since the server is not accepting any raw request

```
Future orderConfirmation(CartConfirmationModel cd, orderNotifyData) {
    var dataMap = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();

    var orders = [];

    for (var item in orderNotifyData.items) {
      var productMap = {
        'product_id': item.productId,
        'qty': item.qty,
      };
      orders.add(productMap);
    }

    dataMap['customer_id'] = cd.customerId;

    **//dataMap['orderLine'] = orders; // if i add orders to dataMap i get this error**

    return http
        .post(API + '/orders/create', headers: key, body: dataMap)
        .then((data) {
      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

        return jsonData['Result'];
      }
    });
  }
```

// Server Response which means server successfully receiving and status 200 is return

```
Map (2 items)
1:"Result" -> Map (1 item)
 key:"Code"
 value:200
0:"Code" -> 200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not encoding the body of the request.

```
 Future orderConfirmation(CartConfirmationModel cd, orderNotifyData) {
    var dataMap = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
    var orders = [];
    for (var item in orderNotifyData.items) {
      var productMap = {
        'product_id': item.productId,
        'qty': item.qty,
      };
      orders.add(productMap);
    }

    dataMap['customer_id'] = cd.customerId;

    dataMap['orderLine'] = orders;

    return http
        .post(API + '/orders/create', headers: key, body: jsonEncode(dataMap))
        .then((data) {
      if (data.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

        return jsonData['Result'];
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: the post method in http expecting body as a String. The jsonEncode will translate your Map to a string so that it can insert in your request body.